# Batch script. how to close connections from one ip address?

Tags: windows, batch-file, port, tcp

i have a problem with  application and i want to write a batch script which is be able to close all connections from one IP expect the last.

this is output of netstat. I want to close all connections expect the last one.

```
 10.10.10.10:2299      192.168.10.2:34624   ESTABLISHED
 10.10.10.10:2299      192.168.10.2:34761   ESTABLISHED
 10.10.10.10:2299      192.168.10.2:34764   ESTABLISHED
 10.10.10.10:2299      192.168.10.2:35001   ESTABLISHED
```

i'm newbie to batch scripting and need help with my code..

```
set ips=netstat -ano | find "192.168.10." | find "2299"
set closeip
set close port

for %%ip in %ips% do (

don't know what to write here :(


#currports util
#C:\cports\cports.exe /close * * %closeip% %closeport%
```

thank for your attention!

Comment: Kill the app that holds those other connections open. What exactly is the problem you are having here? It's not unusual for an application to have multiple connections open simultaneously.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing `BASH` and `batch-file` syntax.

Comment: i know that is unsual for app. but i have a memory leak in app and the last port is alive. other ports zombies...So i can't kill all app or restart it. i must close connections without restarting the app.

Comment: Why would you use NETSTAT to list the ports.  CurrPorts can do the same thing.  If you are going to use it to kill the port, you might as well use it to list the ports as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so recently i used a powershell script.
 I used `Get-NetTCPConnection` and `filter by "CreationTime"` and it worked like a charm!